# LinearLayout displays only one image out of Image List Object programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, parse-platform

I'm trying to fetch images for a particular user from Parse Cloud. The below code is only showing one image in full size but the rest are not shown or sometimes one next image in the list is showing up but utterly very small size.

```
val query = ParseQuery.getQuery<ParseObject>("image")
        query.whereEqualTo("username", username)
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findInBackground { objects, e ->
            if(e == null && objects.isNotEmpty()) {
                for (row in objects) {
                    val parseFile = row.get("image") as ParseFile

                    parseFile.getDataInBackground { data, exception ->
                        if(exception == null && data != null) {
                            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.size)
                            val imageView = ImageView(applicationContext)
                            with(imageView) {
                                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                                setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                            }
                            linearLayout.addView(imageView)
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, exception.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide some more code and info, so we can help you better.

Comment: put linearLayout in ScrollView and set its height to wrap_content.

Comment: @EliasFazel thanks man that worked like a charm. You're a god sent.

Comment: @EliasFazel about time, I was waiting for that... It's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put linearLayout in ScrollView and set its height to wrap_content.